# Django: Javascript error with alert box displaying values

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am creating a web application that will serve as a grocery store. The way I set it up is so the customer can come onto the website, click on the items that they would like to purchase, and then click a submit button to purchase those items. The problem I am running into is that my Javascript is not printing the correct values. In both spots, it says undefined. I will put a picture below for reference.

views.py

```
def inventory(request):
    products = request.POST.getlist('products')
    for product in products:
        a = Post.objects.get(title=product)
        a.quantity = a.quantity -1
        a.save()
    print(products)
    return redirect('blog-home')
```

home.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'js' %}" method="POST" id="menuForm">
      {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.quantity > 0 %}
            <article class="media content-section">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2">{{ post.category }}</a>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" >{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
                <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="product_{{ post.id }}" value="{{ post.title }}" form="menuForm" name="products" > Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
              </input>
              </div>
            </article>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      <button id="btn" type="submit" form="menuForm">Confirm Purchase</button>
    </form>
<script src="{% static "JS/javascript.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock content %}
```

javascript.js

```
function getSelectedCheckboxValues(name) {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
    let values = [];
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
    });
    return values, tPrice;

var price = 0;
var tPrice =0;
if (values=='Milk'){
    var MPrice = 3.99
    tPrice = price+MPrice;
}
if (values == 'Cheese'){
    var CPrice = 4.50
    tPrice = price + CPrice;
}
if (values == 'Yogurt'){
    var YPrice = 1.99
    tPrice = price + YPrice;
}
}

const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    alert('You ordered: ' + getSelectedCheckboxValues('products')+
        '\nTotal Price: $'+ getSelectedCheckboxValues('tPrice'));
});
```

[image: Javascript Error]

Comment: Maybe you can add console.log after each line to see where the problem come from

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are passing the parameter to the function `getSelectedCheckboxValues` as a string when you call them in the alert which is completely wrong.
Also you are directly comparing values list with strings which is not possible. You need to loop over the list and then compare the different elements with the different products. I will also recommend to create an object instead of the list and keep the product name as key and its price as value.